# How to get State, City, Place, Street Name, Zip Code from Google Map Marker Using Angular Google Maps

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I am using angular-google-maps on my user registration page. I would liket to get the State, City, Place, Street Name, Zip Code from the Map Marker I place on map. How to achieve it ?

```
<ui-gmap-google-map ng-if="map.view" center="property.Location" zoom="map.zoom">
    <ui-gmap-marker events="map.events" idkey="'1'" coords='property.Location' options="{draggable:true}" icon="'images/icon/ic_location_city_24px.svg'"></ui-gmap-marker>
```

Controller Code

```
$scope.map = {
            zoom: 11,
            markers: [],
            events: {
                dragend: function (mapModel, eventName, marker, orignalEventArgs) {
                    console.log(marker);
                    var e = originalEventArgs[0];
                    var lat = e.latLng.lat(),lon = e.latLng.lng();
                    var marker = {
                        id: Date.now(),
                        coords: {
                            latitude: lat,
                            longitude: lon
                        }
                    };
                    $scope.map.markers.push(marker);
                    console.log($scope.map.markers);
                    $scope.$apply();
                }
            },
            view: true
        };
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

Comment: Please check this out,

     http://jsfiddle.net/Wijmo/Rqcsj/